# Detect user activity with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a turn-based game in which the server may send messages to the javascript client at random times. When the client receives these messages, it puts an asterisk at the document's title. My problem is, how do I detect that the user is viewing the page, so that I can remove the asterisk as soon as the user has seen the new messages?
For instance, how does Gmail and Facebook do it? I heard that one cannot put an `onfocus` property on the `body` object.

I would also like to know why the body doens't have the onfocus property.

Comment: `document.hidden` or `document.visibilityState`. [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pagevisibility)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not listen for the `focus` and `blur` events on `window`?

```
window.addEventListener('focus', onFocus); // window has focus
window.addEventListener('blur', onBlur); // window lost focus
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check `document.hidden`, or use `document.visibilityState` [for more options](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/PageVisibility/Overview.html#VisibilityState).

[Support is pretty good.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pagevisibility)

Comment: Good summary can be seen on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API

Comment: I can't get this to work on firefox when I minimize the window. It only triggers when I change tabs.